# i want To Join 4 tables in SQL SERVER Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have 4 tables

1)Tbl_Retailer
2)Tbl_Draw
3)tbl_Abc
4)tbl_ABACBC

Tbl_Retailer is Parent Table. And The common Column In all  Tables is RetailerID(Foreign key) Parent Column Is Tbl_Retailer.ID,

and also one more Column Is Common In rest 3 tables (Tbl_Draw,Tbl_Abc,TblABACBC),that is CreatedDate
How to join this tables without data repeatation? i allready tried but it repeats columns (ID,CreatedDate,RetailerID) please help me

Comment: Join without repetition how? Taking the latest record only from each of the 3 tables? Only you can decide what is to happen to all the repeated data, but if you don't decide, and one foreign table has 10 rows per retailer ID, another has 20 and the tire has 30 you'll end up with 6000 rows per retailer if you just join on retailer id

Comment: no i want to take all records matching with Retailer_ID And also GROUP BY   CreatedDate

Comment: Show us your attempt, what you got, and what you want instead. Without anything to work with, we are unable to help you. See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips to improve your question.

Comment: I'm not sure how you think GROUP BY createddate will help; tell me more - perhaps GROUP means something different to you than it does to me. Put some example data on your question and the results you would want that data to give

Comment: sure sir i ll check it out and wil make my quastions clear.after this ...i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Select distinct?